# How do I create a user and a group when they don't exist

Tags: linux, shell

This is the first time I have attempted to create a script and I can't figure out how to create a user when the "user does not exist."
Same problem for the group too "group does not exist."

```
#!/bin/bash!

echo "Enter a user name: "
read name

if grep $name /etc/passwd > /dev/null
then
    echo "user $name is on this system."
else
    echo "user $name does not exist." 
fi

echo "Enter a group name: "
read name

if grep $name /etc/group > /dev/null
then
    echo "$name group is on this system."
else
    echo "$name group does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Your grep will match substrings. So if there's a user named `abcde`, and they ask to make `bcd`, it will say that the username already exists. You can use `grep -w` option to match whole words.

Comment: If someone wants to make a user named `bash` it will fail because `/bin/bash` appears in the file.

Comment: Generally you add the group with `groupadd [-g GID] groupname` where the `-g GID` is optional if you want to assign a specific group-ID. Then use `useradd -u UID -g [GID name] -G [list of other groups] -m username` Where you can set the primary group for the user to the new GID with `-g` (name or GID) and list of supplemental groups after `-G` telling the system to create the `/home/username` directory with `-m`.

Comment: `getent $db "$name" >/dev/null` (where `$db` is `passwd` or `group`)  instead of grep avoids the problems Barmer noted and searches all databases supported by NSS not just flat files.